# Adding vertex in graph using boost as the elements of a vector

Tags: boost

I have a vector say [3,2,1,8,7]. The vertices of the Graph should be 3,2,1,8,7. How can i create this in a loop. Can i use add_vertex function of boost in a loop which iterates through this vector ? Or which is the best way to add these vector elements as the vertices of the graph ?

This is what i have tried. Group4 is the vector of [3,2,1,8,7].

```
    struct Vertex{ float foo;};
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex > Graph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
    Graph g(Group4.size());
    vertex_t Vertices[Group4.size()];
        for(T_INDEX i=0;i<Group4.size();i++){
            Vertices[i] = boost::add_vertex(Group4[i], g);
        }

        g[Group4[0]].foo = 3.4;

        boost::add_edge(Group4[0],Group4[2],g);
        boost::add_edge(Group4[1],Group4[2],g);
```

I am getting errors.

Comment: Well, of course you can use a loop. What makes you think you can't? BTW: As it stands, this looks a lot like homework and that you expect someone else to write code for you. That's not going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Vertices[i] = boost::add_vertex(Group4[i], g);
```

This adds a vertex with "Group4[i]" as the bundle property. That doesn't work because it's not a `Vertex` object. Instead, try

```
   Vertices[i] = add_vertex(Vertex{3.4}, g);
```

Or indeed even

```
   Vertices[i] = add_vertex({3.4}, g);
```

That works:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b68b4b312ae40e2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct Vertex {
    float foo;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex> Graph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
using T_INDEX = Graph::vertices_size_type;

int main() {
    std::vector<int> Group4{ 3, 2, 1, 8, 7 };

    Graph g(Group4.size());
    std::vector<vertex_t> vertices(Group4.size());

    for (T_INDEX i = 0; i < Group4.size(); i++) {
        vertices[i] = add_vertex(Vertex{ 3.4 }, g);
    }

    boost::add_edge(Group4[0], Group4[2], g);
    boost::add_edge(Group4[1], Group4[2], g);
}
```

> **Note** I replaced your VLA with a `std::vector` because variable-length arrays are non-standard

### The Real Question

Looking at the rest of the code, it seems to me that really you are struggling with the mapping from the vertex "ids" (3, 2, 1, 8, 7) to the vertex descriptors.

What you have works, but from the looks of it, you could just use the indices directly as vertex descriptors.

> **Note** This works only if your vertex container supports integral                                                 descriptors and you will not have a very sparse id-space (e.g. if you have ids 1,2,3 and 88837674 you will allocate memory for 88837675 vertices, which is not efficient.

The code could become:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a743a8585e6a21c8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct Vertex { float foo; };
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex> Graph;

#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp> // print_graph

int main() {
    std::vector<int> Group4 { 3, 2, 1, 8, 7 };
    Graph g(1 + *std::max_element(Group4.begin(), Group4.end()));

    for (int v : Group4)
        g[v].foo = 3.4;

    boost::add_edge(0, 2, g);
    boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);

    print_graph(g);
}
```

This prints the graph, as:

```
0 --> 2 
1 --> 2 
2 --> 
3 --> 
4 --> 
5 --> 
6 --> 
7 --> 
8 -->
```

Comment: Is it possible like I want the vertices only to be from that vector. That is the vertices should be only [3,2,1,8,7] and should not contain [0,4,5,6].??